# No visible @interface for 'UIApplication' declares the selector 'registerForRemoteNotifications:' AppDelegate.m

Tags: push-notification, ios8, xcode6, appdelegate

I just switched to xcode 6 and ios8, I was trying to fix some warnings. The warnings were about some deprecated methods. So I changed the code in AppDelegate.h for push notifications to work with iOS 8 but I get errors

old code(xcode 5, iOS7)

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

New Code for iOS8

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications:
 (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

How Can resolve this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read the documentation. This is not how you use `registerForRemoteNotifications`. You call `registerUserNotificationSettings:` with the appropriate settings, and finally call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];` to register.